# Number of labeled graphs satisfying a degree sequence

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Say we have two sequences of integers $d^\text{in}$ and $d^\text{out}$ representing the in- and out-degree sequences of a directed graph. How many (possibly isomorphic) graphs are there that satisfy this sequence?

[One paper](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/icml2006_BezakovaKS06.pdf) seems to think this is a simple matter, and uses the formula
$$
\frac{m!}{\prod_i d^\text{in}_i!\prod_i d^\text{out}_i!}
$$

My knowledge of combinatorics isn't good enough to prove the correctness of this, but I can sort of see how it works, tying up the outgoing links to ingoing links and dividing out the results that produce the same graph.

[Another paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870809003697), published later, gives only an approximate formula using a far more complex method.

Is the first method incorrect? If so why?

Additionally, if I want to get a decent estimate for this problem (directed or undirected graphs) without too much fuss, is there a simple method available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:  That first formula does not work for counting directed graphs with prescribed degrees (I assume multiple edges and loops are allowed).  One example where it fails is if $d^{out} = (2, 2, 0)$ and $d^{in} = (1, 1, 2)$.  In this case, the formula gives $3$ but there are $4$ such graphs.

To see the problem, consider trying to count the situation where $u$ has edges going to $v$ and $w$.  The formula does do well to divide out by $d^{out}(u)!$, since the $m!$ total would count a vertex $u$ connecting to $v$ and $w$ different from that vertex connecting with $w$ and $v$.   Since we want to count these as the same, we divide by $d^{out}(u)! = 2$.  Similarly with dividing out by $d^{in}(v)$.  The problem is if you had two edges going from $u$ to $v$.  The $m!$ counts two different possibilities, but then we divide by $d^{out}(u)! = 2$ and $d^{in}(v)! = 2$, thus dividing by $4$.  This is essentially an over-count of how much we should divide.

I don't know how you'd find a better answer besides the second paper you linked to.

Comment: The paper I linked gives the formula as the number of graphs _without_ multiple edges (I think loops are allowed, they're not explicit about that). Can you tell if the formular is correct for such a case, or does it stilll overcount?

Comment: The overcount is in the denominator, so it's actually an undercount all told if multiple edges are allowed.  The first formula doesn't count graphs without multiple edges either -- again with $d^{out} = (2, 2, 0)$ and $d^{in} = (1, 1, 2)$, the formula gives $3$ but now there are only $2$ such graphs (or $1$ if loops are discounted).  There is just nothing in the formula to prevent counting graphs with multiple edges.   Not sure how bad it would be as an approximation.